# Convert Leaf Nodes Into Child under Child for Json Object In D3js tree

Tags: javascript, node.js

The Overall Context is to find the leaf node of every parent(x) and children(x1) if there are more than 2 leaf nodes make them the child's as one under another
I Tried to use loadash in Nodejs but I was unable to get the expected result

I have a JSON Data

```
{
"Id": "1",
"name": "x",
"parent": "",
"children": [{
        "Id": "2",
        "name": "x1",
        "parent": "1",
        "children": [{
                "Id": "3",
                "name": "x2",
                "parent": "2"
            }, {
                "Id": "4",
                "name": "x3",
                "parent": "2"
            },
            {
                "Id": "5",
                "name": "x4",
                "parent": "2"
            },
            {
                "Id": "6",
                "name": "x5",
                "parent": "2"

            },
            {
                "Id": "7",
                "name": "x6",
                "parent": "2"
            },
            {
                "Id": "8",
                "name": "x7",
                "parent": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "9",
        "name": "x8",
        "parent": "1"
    },
    {
        "Id": "10",
        "name": "x10",
        "parent": "1"
    }, {
        "Id": "11",
        "name": "x9",
        "parent": "1"
    },
    {
        "Id": "12",
        "name": "x11",
        "parent": "1"
    }
]
```

}

I would like to change into the below format

```
{
"Id": "1",
"name": "x",
"parent": "",
"children": [{
        "Id": "2",
        "name": "x1",
        "parent": "1",
        "children": [{
                "Id": "3",
                "name": "x2",
                "IC": "Yes",
                "parent": "2",
                "children": [{
                    "Id": "5",
                    "name": "x4",
                    "IC": "Yes",
                    "parent": "2",
                    "children": [{
                        "Id": "7",
                        "parent": "2",
                        "name": "x6"
                    }]
                }]
            },
            {
                "Id": "4",
                "name": "x3",
                "IC": "Yes",
                "parent": "2",
                "children": [{
                    "Id": "5",
                    "name": "x5",
                    "IC": "Yes",
                    "parent": "2",
                    "children": [{
                        "Id": "7",
                        "name": "x7",
                        "IC": "Yes",
                        "parent": "2"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "9",
        "name": "x8",
        "parent": "1",
        "children": [{
            "Id": "10",
            "name": "x10",
            "IC": "Yes",
            "parent": "1"
        }]
    },
    {
        "Id": "11",
        "name": "x9",
        "parent": "1",
        "children": [{
            "Id": "11",
            "name": "x11",
            "parent": "1",
            "IC": "Yes"
        }]
    }
]
```

}

Note:
1. If there are 8 leaf nodes it should be split 4+4, 
2. If there are 9 leaf nodes it should be split 5+4, 
3. In the same way, If it has 13 it can be split into 7+6.

any help would be appreciated 
thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't appear  to be valid JSON. Please run it through https://jsonlint.com/ and repost.

Comment: Thanks ggorlen for mentioning that I have put the valid JSON now

Comment: Thanks. I'm not 100% clear on your requested transformation, though. Do you only want to consider leaf nodes in the root object at depth 0? Because `x1` has more than 2 leaf nodes but wasn't altered. How do you handle a case with an odd number of leaf nodes? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes it is for the root and the children (x1)

Comment: If it's for the children of `x1`, would you mind reflecting your output example to show that? I don't want to code something up for you that isn't what you're asking for.

Comment: I have updated my output JSON formate Sorry for the inconveniences

Comment: All right, so it looks like if there are 8 children, you want two children with 4 linked nodes each? What do you do if there are 9 children? Please write a very detailed and specific explanation of your transformation, otherwise you're requiring folks to make assumptions about what you want.

Comment: If it has 9 It can be split into 5+4 In the same way, If it has 13 it can be split into 7+6

Comment: OK--I recommend updating your post to state everything you've written in the comments here.

Comment: Sure ggoreln Thanks

Comment: How do I know that x10 should be the child of x8 and x11 the child of x9? Why not x11 be the child of x8?

Comment: It Doesn't have to be in a particular Order X11 also can be the child x8 Ex:let says if I have 5 leaf nodes under a parent I would expect 3 as on group 2 as one group I don't want them to be in specific order.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: You want your output tree to be randomly generated from the the input tree?

Comment: Yes Based on the input tree it should generate output randomly.

Comment: I get a response from the server in flat JSON it contains parent and children I am mapping child to right parent using loadash(Nodejs) here is the link I used to map parent-child (https://gist.github.com/alonronin/2592a6a81db67804db1f) I am getting the nested JSON REf:aboveinputJSON. But I want the leaf nodes as above mentioned JSON(OutputJson).

Comment: In the link you provided, each node knows who their parent are. That's not the case in your example.

Comment: I have updated my latest JSON which will contain parent and child mapping which I got this latest response in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will take all leaf nodes and create 2 even branches from them. The output is not identical to yours, but you mention in your comments that the branches can be built randomly from the leaf nodes, and this code respects that requirement.

```
const input = {
  "name": "x",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "x1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "x2"
        },
        {
          "name": "x3"
        },
        {
          "name": "x4"
        },
        {
          "name": "x5"
        },
        {
          "name": "x6"
        },
        {
          "name": "x7"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "x8"
    },
    {
      "name": "x10"
    },
    {
      "name": "x9"
    },
    {
      "name": "x11"
    }
  ]
};

function cutLeafNodes(node){
  if(!node.children){
    return;
  }

  const leaves = [];
  const branches = [];
  node.children.forEach(child => {
    if(child.children){
      branches.push(child);
    } else {
      leaves.push(child);
    }
  });
  node.children = branches;

  return leaves;
}

function reorderLeaves(nodes){
  if(!nodes){
    return;
  }

  const midpoint = nodes.length / 2;
  const newChildren = [];
  newChildren.push(createAncestry(nodes.splice(0, midpoint)));
  newChildren.push(createAncestry(nodes));
  return newChildren;
}

function createAncestry(nodes){
  let currentChild = nodes[0];
  const firstChild = currentChild;
  for (let i = 1; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    currentChild.children = [nodes[i]];
    currentChild = currentChild.children[0];
  }
  return firstChild;
}

function reorganizeTree(node){
  const leaves = cutLeafNodes(node);

  if(node.children){
    node.children.forEach(child => {
      reorganizeTree(child);
    });
  }

  if(leaves){
    const newBranches = reorderLeaves(leaves);
    newBranches.forEach(branch =>{
      node.children.push(branch);
    })
  }

  return node;
}

const output = reorganizeTree(input);
console.debug(output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Guillaume CR I spent some many nights for this I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Sri You're welcome. It was an interesting problem to solve.

Comment: @ Guillaume CR I need help with small thing How do I add "IC": "Yes",  for all leaf nodes in the JSON.Thanks for the help in advance.I tried to add but it is adding as a new object instead of adding to leaf node

Comment: @Sri node.IC = 'Yes';

Comment: Hi Guillaume.  I am trying to make half nodes when the count of leaf nodes is more than "6"  `function reorderLeaves(nodes){
  if(!nodes){
    return;
  }
const newChildren = [];
if(nodes.length>5) 
{
 const midpoint = nodes.length;
 newChildren.push(createAncestry(nodes.splice(0, midpoint/2)));
 newChildren.push(createAncestry(nodes));

}
 return newChildren;
 
} when i trying this i am unable to see the expected out put.  If you could let me know where i am doing wrong that would be great thanks
`

Comment: @Sri I'm not sure I understand the problem. It's probably best if you ask a new question including your expected and actual output.